# Didactic/complete non blog/cms rails tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I've known ruby for a while, but never used rails seriously until one month ago, currently I am a PHP developer, but got a rails job that will start soon and want to get up to speed as much as I can in the soonest possible.

I finished rails for zombies, bought a course in udemy that i didn't liked, checked a couple of books, and followed quite a few tutorials, but most of them were pretty trivial, and all were either a blog or cms.

I wonder if there's any didactic/extensive rails tutorial for another kind of app, a shopping cart, an erp, etc.

I saw the railspace book but seems a little dated and quite long. A good idea I came across was to build a reddit clone in rails https://github.com/schneems/reddit_on_rails

tl;dr Looking for a full, weel explained rail tutorial that is not a blog

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people seem to be using http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

What I did when I started learning rails:

- Work through one tutorial
- Watch all the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)
- Start any project and apply the newly learned stuff

The tutorial should help with understanding how rails works. After that you should be able to understand what the railscasts (or any other shorter tutorials) are about, and be able to apply that.